# Can't start Samba on Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, fedora, kerberos

I'm trying to get Samba running as an Active Directory Domain Controller with Kerberos, but when I try to start its service I get a strange error that I can't seem to find anywhere on the internet.
Running

```
sudo systemctl start samba
```

fails, and

```
sudo systemctl status samba
```

afterwards gives
[this](https://pastebin.com/pNhtbjt9).

The error seems to be at

`samba_terminate: samba_terminate of samba 1363: KDC: Unable to start kpasswd server`

but I haven't been able to find anyone else having this error anywhere.

As far as I can tell, Kerberos is running fine;

```
sudo systemctl status kadmin.service
```

and

```
sudo systemctl status krb5kdc.service
```

give this:

[kadmin status](https://pastebin.com/xFKi4Baj)

[krb5kdc status](https://pastebin.com/JRhEu8cM)

The only thing weird I see in there is in krb5kdc's status, with

```
krb5kdc.service: Can't open PID file /run/krb5kdc.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
```

But I've looked that up and it seems that it doesn't matter; just an error where krb5kdc tries to access a file before one of its child processes can create it. (And checking that directory, the file does exist)

Looking at KDC's logs at /var/log/samba/mit_kdc.log reveals [this](https://pastebin.com/d2Fb4zjq) from the last reboot I did.

I really have no idea what's going on; something's got to have been set up wrong, but I don't know what.

I'm running Fedora 31 and Samba version 4.11.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed; turned out it was because I had already started the kadmin and krb5kdc services, and since samba starts those services itself, this was causing the error.